# unix diff side-to-side results?

Tags: bash, unix, diff

How can I plot the results of a unix diff command side-to-side instead of one difference after the other? See below for an example:

```
    diff /tmp/test1  /tmp/test2
1,4c1,2
< asfdsadf
< asdfsad
< fsaf
< fdsadf
---
> asdfsafdsf
> saf
6,8d3
< sadf
< asdf
< sadf
10d4
< fasd
12,13c6,14
< sadfa
< fd
---
> sadf
> sadf
> sadf
> sadf
> sadf
> sadf
> sadf
> sadf
> safa
```

I would like to have something like:

```
diff /tmp/test1  /tmp/test2
1,4c1,2
< asfdsadf       > asdfsafdsf
< asdfsad        > saf       
< fsaf
< fdsadf
---
6,8d3
< sadf
< asdf
< sadf
10d4
< fasd
12,13c6,14
< sadfa               > sadf
< fd              > sadf
---               > sadf
              > sadf
              > sadf
              > sadf
              > sadf
              > sadf
              > safa
```

Comment: vimdiff can help too. Good luck.

Comment: `sdiff -s  f1 f2`

Comment: I don't know why, but 'diff -y' and 'sdiff' don't seem to maintain the formatting when copy/pasting...however vimdiff does...(but remember... <esc>:q! to quit)
Ah, as per below, diff needs '--expand-tabs' to use spaces instead of tabs :D

Answer (score 283, accepted):

From `man diff`, you can use `-y` to do side-by-side.

```
-y, --side-by-side
       output in two columns
```

Hence, say:

```
diff -y /tmp/test1  /tmp/test2
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a                $ cat b
hello                  hello
my name                my name
is me                  is you
```

Let's compare them:

```
$ diff -y a b
hello                                                           hello
my name                                                         my name
is me                                                         | is you
```

Comment: Note that `diff` has a hard-coded maximum output width (130 columns). Add the diff option `--width=$COLUMNS` to set this to your terminal width.

Comment: Also for large diffs just pipe into less like this for a nice scrolly/searchable diff: `diff -y /tmp/test1  /tmp/test2 | less`

Comment: check out colordiff

Comment: better `diff --width=$COLUMNS --suppress-common-lines --side-by-side a b`

Comment: @rubo77 Depending on how you have set up tab expansion, you may also want to expand tabs to spaces so that the output lines up properly in columns: `diff --expand-tabs --width=$COLUMNS --suppress-common-lines --side-by-side a b`

Answer (score 110):

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1 file2
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer because just `-y` shows common lines as well which is not same as just `diff` and the original question. +1.

Comment: better `diff -W $COLUMNS --suppress-common-lines -y file1 file2`

Comment: late to the party :-( . but what is `-W $COLUMNS`. Can someone eloborate

Comment: @samshers `-W` defines the width, which is useful if you have a big terminal, and want to use it. `$COLUMNS` is a built-in which tells the width of your current terminal. Frankly, I don't see its benefit for my usage.

Comment: @mazunki, I find it useful when using a large terminal because long lines may get truncated with just `-y --suppress-common-lines`. I also add the `--color` modifier thus getting `$ diff --color -y --suppress-common-lines -W $COLUMNS  file1 file2`.

Answer (score 68):

From icdiff's [homepage](http://www.jefftk.com/icdiff):

[image]

> Your terminal can display color, but most diff tools don't make good use of it. By highlighting changes, icdiff can show you the differences between similar files without getting in the way. This is especially helpful for identifying and understanding small changes within existing lines.
>
> Instead of trying to be a diff replacement for all circumstances, the goal of icdiff is to be a tool you can reach for to get a better picture of what changed when it's not immediately obvious from diff.

IMHO, its output is much more readable than `diff -y`.

Comment: It has no option for directories preceding files, unfortunately.

Answer (score 26):

You can use:

```
sdiff  file1 file2
```

or

```
diff -y file1 file2
```

or

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```

for side by side display.

Comment: I was wondering what's the difference between `diff -y` and `sdiff`? Their output looks identical to me.

Comment: Vimdiff!!! Awsome

Answer (score 13):

You should have `sdiff` for side-by-side merge of file differences. Take a read of `man sdiff` for the full story.

Comment: On my system (GNU/Linx) `sdiff` appears to do the same thing as `diff -y` and the `sdiff` info documentation says it's deprecated: "'sdiff' without '--output' ('-o') produces a side-by-side difference.  This usage is obsolete; use the '--side-by-side' ('-y')
option of 'diff' instead."

Answer (score 10):

You can use `vimdiff`.

Example:

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use:

```
diff -y fileA.txt fileB.txt | colordiff
```

It shows the output splitted in two colums and colorized! (`colordiff`)

Comment: Just tried it on OSX and it does not work here. Maybe its for linux only.

Comment: colordiff isn't on osx.

Comment: You can install _colordiff_ on OSX using _Homebrew_
`brew install colordiff`

See [colordiff formula](http://formulae.brew.sh/formula/colordiff)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why the piping is preferable over directly using `colordiff` at the beginning?

Answer (score 9):

If your files have inconsistent use of spaces and tabs, you may find it helpful to include the `-t` argument to expand the tabs:

```
diff -ty file1 file2
```

Answer (score 7):

Try [cdiff](https://github.com/ymattw/cdiff) - View colored, incremental diff in workspace or from stdin with side by side and auto pager support.

Comment: If you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer, you must disclose your affiliation https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 6):

Use the `-y` option:

```
diff -y file1 file2
```

Answer (score 4):

Enhanced diff command with color, side by side and alias

Let's say the file contents are like:

```
cat /tmp/test1.txt
1
2
3
4
5
8
9
```

and

```
cat /tmp/test2.txt
1
1.5
2
4
5
6
7
```

Now comparing side-by-side

```
diff --width=$COLUMNS --suppress-common-lines --side-by-side --color=always /tmp/test1.txt /tmp/test2.txt
                                                                              > 1.5
3                                                                             <
8                                                                             | 6
9                                                                             | 7
```

You can define alias to use

```
alias diff='diff --width=$COLUMNS --suppress-common-lines --side-by-side --color=always'
```

Then new diff result:

```
diff /tmp/test1.txt /tmp/test2.txt
                                                                              > 1.5
3                                                                             <
8                                                                             | 6
9                                                                             | 7
```