# Compare and display two files side by side

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

How can I compare and print data from two text files to one in Shell.
Lets take two examples A.txt and B.txt

Example:

```
$cat A.txt  
FName   User1  
EmpID   1234  
Mobile1 000-000-000  
EMail   user1@aol.com


$cat B.txt
FName   User2
LName   LastName  
EmpID   2345  
Phone   00-1234567  
EMail   user2@aol.com
```

and the result should be like

```
FName   User1           User2
LName                   LastName
EmpID   1234            2345
Mobile1 000-000-000     
Phone                   00-1234567
EMail   user1@aol.com   user2@aol.com
```

I have tried of using `pr -m -t A.txt B.txt` and the output of it is getting clubbed the files content to one.

Also tried of using sdiff but unable to get output

Can any help me or else give some idea on this.

Thanks,
Vardhan

Comment: Does `diff -y A.txt B.txt` work for you?

Comment: Related: [unix diff side-to-side results?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17195308/1983854)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the general approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR{ a[$1] = $2; next }
{ a[$1]; b[$1] = $2 }
END {
    for (key in a) {
        printf "%-10s%-15s%-15s\n", key, a[key], b[key]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk A.txt B.txt
LName                    LastName
Phone                    00-1234567
Mobile1   000-000-000
EMail     user1@aol.com  user2@aol.com
EmpID     1234           2345
FName     User1          User2
```

You'd need to provide the logic for how a script would know to output "FName" before "LName", "Mobile1" comes before rather than after "Phone" and the order of the other fields in your output if you care about that. One possibility would be to hard-code the keys:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ split("FName LName EmpID Mobile1 Phone Email", keys) }
NR==FNR{ a[$1] = $2; next }
{ b[$1] = $2 }
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr in keys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%-10s%-15s%-15s\n", key, a[key], b[key]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk A.txt B.txt
FName     User1          User2
LName                    LastName
EmpID     1234           2345
Mobile1   000-000-000
Phone                    00-1234567
Email
```

Comment: Does `a[$1];` put a key in the associative array if the item doesn't exist? (yes) never tought of it, nice to know!

Comment: Yes it does. That's why when you want to test for a key existing in an array you need to use `if (key in array)` rather than `if (array[key])` because (among other problems) the latter would add `key` to `array` if it didn't exist and so a later `for (key in array)` loop would have undesirable behavior.

Comment: What are the changes need to be done if there is **6 columns** in two different files..  Waiting for your update.. Thank you @EdMorton

Comment: That could mean several things. post a new question with sample input and expected output.

Comment: Posted new question.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121066/how-can-i-compare-and-print-data-from-different-text-files-to-one-in-shell)

Comment: Why did you un-accept this as the answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can almost just do:

```
join -a 1 -a 2 A.txt B.txt
```

But you lose some spacing.  Try:

```
{ join A.txt B.txt; 
join -v 2 A.txt B.txt | awk '{print $1, ".", $2}';
join -v 1 A.txt B.txt; } | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can obtain a csv file that you can format as you like

```
% fieldjoin () { awk '
    NR==FNR{val[$1]=$2",";next}
           {if($1 in val){
             val[$1]=val[$1] $2} else {
             val[$1]=","$2}}
    END {for(k in val) print k "," val[k]}' "$1" "$2" ; }
% fieldjoin A.txt B.txt
LName,,LastName
Phone,,00-1234567
Mobile1,000-000-000,
EMail,user1@aol.com,user2@aol.com
EmpID,1234,2345
FName,User1,User2
%
```

Comment: I see that you removed your comment... I'm sorry if you did it following my comment, because your remarks on the availability of the last record and the POSIX specification were useful _per se_. To summarize Ed's removed comment: (1) not all the implementations of `awk` give you `$0`, `$1` etc when you execute the code in an `END` clause (2) POSIX limits itself to require that `NR` is available in the  `END` body.

Answer (score 0):

You could just `cut` out what you want & `paste a.txt b.txt` together.

`man cut` & `man paste` for more details.