# How can I compare and print data from different text files to one in Shell.

Tags: bash, shell, unix, join, awk

How can I compare and print data from different text files to one in Shell.

I have captures `NAS` details of three different boxes using `SSH`, now I need to combine all the three text files to one file and **MOUNT NAME** should be in the first column and if the same **MOUNT** were present in he three boxes then it should print in same line and if the **MOUNT** is presented only in **BOX_B** and **BOX_C** then **MOUNT name** should present in first column and Column for **Box_A** should be kept blank

Lets take two examples **df_BoxA.txt** and **df_BoxB.txt** and **df_BoxC.txt**

Example:

```
$cat df_BoxA.txt  
/logs/boxA      2G     1.2G     7.7G    62%             NAS:/logs/boxA
/data/boxA      2G     1.8G     2.0G    91%             NAS:/data/boxA 
/apps/boxA      2G     1.4G     5.7G    72%             NAS:/apps/boxA 
/data/java      1G     67M      9.3G    7%              NAS:/data/java
/home/admin     10G    4.6G     54G     46%             NAS:/home/admin
/admin/arch     10G    8.3G     19G     83%             NAS:/admin/arch
/apps/dist      10G    8.3G     19G     83%             NAS:/apps/dist



$cat df_BoxB.txt  
/logs/boxA      2G     1.2G     7.7G    62%             NAS:/logs/boxB
/data/boxA      2G     1.8G     2.0G    91%             NAS:/data/boxB 
/apps/boxA      2G     1.4G     5.7G    72%             NAS:/apps/boxB 
/home/user      40G    29.3G    107G    74%             NAS:/home/user1 
/data/java      1G     67M      9.3G    7%              NAS:/data/java
/home/admin     10G    4.6G     54G     46%             NAS:/home/admin
/apps/dist      10G    8.3G     19G     83%             NAS:/apps/dist


$cat df_BoxC.txt  
/logs/boxA      2G     1.2G     7.7G    62%             NAS:/logs/boxC
/data/boxA      2G     1.8G     2.0G    91%             NAS:/data/boxC 
/apps/boxA      2G     1.4G     5.7G    72%             NAS:/apps/boxC 
/home/user1     40G    29.3G    107G    74%             NAS:/home/user1 
/home/admin     10G    4.6G     54G     46%             NAS:/home/admin
/admin/arch     10G    8.3G     19G     83%             NAS:/admin/arch
/apps/dist      10G    8.3G     19G     83%             NAS:/apps/dist
```

After combining all the three files the result should be like

```
$cat result.txt 
/logs/boxA   2G     1.2G     7.7G    62% NAS:/logs/boxA 2G  1.2G  7.7G  62% NAS:/logs/boxB  2G   1.2G  7.7G  62% NAS:/logs/boxC
/data/boxA   2G     1.8G     2.0G    91% NAS:/data/boxA 2G  1.8G  2.0G  91% NAS:/data/boxB  2G   1.8G  2.0G  91% NAS:/data/boxC
/apps/boxA   2G     1.4G     5.7G    72% NAS:/apps/boxA 2G  1.4G  5.7G  72% NAS:/apps/boxB  2G   1.4G  5.7G  72% NAS:/apps/boxC 
/data/java   1G     67M     9.3G    7%   NAS:/data/java 1G  67M   9.3G  7%  NAS:/data/java
/home/admin  10G    4.6G     54G     46% NAS:/home/admin10G 4.6G  54G   46% NAS:/home/admin 10G  4.6G  54G   46% NAS:/home/admin
/admin/arch  10G    8.3G     19G     83% NAS:/admin/arch                                    10G  8.3G  19G   83% NAS:/admin/arch
/apps/dist   10G    8.3G     19G     83% NAS:/apps/dist 10G 8.3G  19G   83% NAS:/apps/dist  10G  8.3G  19G   83% NAS:/apps/dist
/home/user                                              40G 29.3G 107G  74% NAS:/home/user1 
/home/user1                                                                                 40G  29.3G 107G  74% NAS:/home/user1
```

I have tried of using `pr` command which is combining of the files which not the required result.

Also tried of using `sdiff` but unable to get result.

Can any one suggest me or can give some idea on this.

Thanks,
Vardhan

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering a "cat" through a "sort|uniq" pipe:

```
cat df_BoxA.txt df_BoxB.txt df_BoxC.txt | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
paste df_BoxA.txt df_BoxB.txt df_BoxC.txt
```

`man paste` for more details.