# Mercurial side-by-side diffs (at max term width)

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, mercurial

I use [extdiff](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ExtdiffExtension) in my `~/.hgrc`...

```
[extensions]
pager =
hgext.extdiff =

[extdiff]
# add new command that runs GNU diff(1) in 'side-by-side' mode
cmd.sdiff = sh
opts.sdiff = -c 'diff -dbB --left-column -y -W `tput cols` $0 $1'

[pager]
pager = LESS='FRX' less
attend = cat, diff, sdiff, glog, log, incoming, outgoing, lg, show, lga
```

This means I can use `hg sdiff README` and use `diff` in [side-by-side mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17195364/667301) for the README file; however, for some reason, the output of `tput cols` above still gives the shell 80 characters when I run it through `hg sdiff`.

If I remove `sdiff` from the `[pager]` extension, my `sdiff` spans the full terminal width...

```
[pager]
pager = LESS='FRX' less
## Removing sdiff fixes the problem with terminal width
attend = cat, diff, glog, log, incoming, outgoing, lg, show, lga
```

Even if I remove `sdiff` from the `[pager]` section and manually pipe through `less` as `hg sdiff | less -FRX`, the diff still spans a full terminal width.  How can I get `[extdiff]` and `[pager]` to allow dynamic terminal width for side-by-side diffs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I have found is

```
[extdiff]
# add new command that runs GNU diff(1) in 'side-by-side' mode
cmd.sdiff = sh
opts.sdiff = -c 'diff -dbB --left-column -y -W `tput cols` $0 $1 | less -FRX'
```

I also remove `sdiff` from the `[pager]` section.  This looks like a Mercurial bug at this point.